# What are ways to ask a question about a direct object in English?

Tags: present-simple, direct-objects, wh-questions

In the sentence: "*They help poor families*", how do we make a question which the answer is "poor families"?

Back in school they taught us that we should use "do" while forming a question in present simple unless the question is asking about the subject. In this example, we say: "Who help poor families?"
But in the case where you want to ask the question where the answer is "poor families", you normally say: "Who do they help?" _at least they way they taught us. However, I noticed somewhere that they used the following structure: "Who they help?"

I wanted to see if I'm missing a grammar or something? Or maybe it is common in speaking and informal writing.
Any help in here would be appreciated.

Comment: **Who they help?** is completely unacceptable to the vast majority of native Anglophones. You'd only see that from non-native speakers OR very poorly-educated AAVE speakers.

Answer (score 2):

If the WH-word is the subject of the question, you don’t need ‘do’.

> What rains on Jupiter?

> Who wants a UZI?

But if the Wh-phrase is the object, then you need ‘do’!

> Which paper do you take to your school?

> What did you do yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard or seen "Who they help?", even in informal English. I would only say "Who do they help?"